# Applying Javascript MVC architecture on existing backend MVC

Tags: django, javascript-framework

We currently have a large implementation done in Django which mostly spit out static HTML. We are planning to implement a javascript modular framework to hook to django's API and define needed routes..etc

But, we do not want to scratch off what we did so far as the site is completely functional for non-js users. The more I read about JavaScript MVC designs, the more I find it impossible to implement the two to work together.

Any ideas of how to proceed in that direction? is there a best practice that someone can follow?

Answer (score 0):

Keep what you got right now as a fail-safe. Create new, separate views meant for Ajax requests that handle the processing of data and respond with appropriately formatted respond data (XML, JSON etc.).

Basically, Django *is* your model. Any action defined by your Javascript controller can either modify the model or the view.

If it modifies the view, there are two options: you either change just the display of data, and thus you just call a Javascript function that alters the HTML, or you display new data. In that case, you have to create a Django view that supplies that data in a format that Javascript can process easily. In your Ajax request, supply a callback (the view part of your Javascript) that handles displaying that data.

If the action modifies the model, you also need to create a Django view that processes the POST data sent by the Ajax request as needed, and returns either the error messages or a success message in a format that is, again, easily processed by Javascript. Again, you should register a callback to your Ajax request that handles the display of the messages returned by Django.

So basically, the only change to your current views would be that you supply the appropriate Javascript code to map the actions to Ajax requests and to handle the data returned by Django for your Ajax requests. Everything else should be done in separate Django views.